# Build skew normal distribution knowing the mean, max, and min

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Say I have a data point with included errors and I want to build some continuous distribution around it.  Normally this might be a Gaussian because one knows the sigma and mean right off the bat.  However, if you have asymmetric errors it becomes a lot harder.  It seems like you should be able to model a Gaussian about a data point with such errors using a skewed normal distribution, let me know if I am wrong.

Essentially, I would like to know if there is a way to generate a standard normal distribution if you know the mean, max, and min?  The mean being the data point, max being the data point plus the upper bound, and min being the data point minus the lower bound.

Comment: Standard normal distributions go from negative infinity to positive infinity; those are min and max respectively.

Comment: Not clear what you are after.  If the distribution has skew, or higher moments, then it is not normal.  Indeed, knowing the mean, st. dev., skew, kurtosis (or higher moments) does not determine a distribution uniquely (sad to say).   Usually one has some a priori model of what sort of distribution some data set ought to have ....is that not the case here?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807398/how-to-generate-distributions-given-mean-sd-skew-and-kurtosis-in-r) might be relevant.  The writers there point to some standard statistical packages which sometimes (but not always) help.  Again, it's usually best to look at the situation to decide what sort of distribution might be expected.

Comment: @lulu There is a distribution known as "the skew normal distribution". I think by mean/min/max the poster is referring to the 16th, 50th, and 84th percentiles of the distribution, in allusion to the error bars (that are usually symmetric).

Comment: @AlexMeiburg  Sure.  But is that what was intended?  The OP asks for a way "to generate a standard normal distribution if you know the mean, max, min."  That might mean "what's the best way to fit a skew normal to the given data", but it seems a bit of a reach.  Perhaps the OP can clarify?

Comment: @Tristan  You can read about the skew normal [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution).  That article shows you how to estimate the required parameters given a sample, assuming you are ok with a maximum likelihood fit (pretty standard).  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Like @AlexMeiburg is saying I want the percentiles of 16th as my minus 50th as my mean and 84th as my positive.  I don't quite have my head wrapped around the idea of a skew normal distribution completely but it seemed like I could represent an asymmetric data point with it.  That is the upper and lower bounds are different but still represented by the 16th and 84th percentile thus giving an equal probability of drawing from such a random sample on either side of the mean.

Comment: @lulu I don't quite so much as have a sample of data to derive a skew normal as much as just one data point.  I ultimately want to be able to randomly draw from a skew normal that is representative of a desired data point as part of a Monte-Carlo simulation.

Comment: Ok, well then the article I linked to should show you how to adapt a Monte Carlo generator for a standard normal to a specified skew normal.  After all, the p.d.f. is directly adapted from the distribution functions of the normal. As the article discusses, you can't get arbitrary skewness this way, but in its range, it's quite a useful family of distributions.